# Calculating $P(Y>1)$, Y follows an random uniform distribution on $[0,X]$ and X follows an exp. distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to calculate $P(Y>1)$ with Y being uniformly distributed on the random interval $[0,X]$ and X being exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda = 1$.

So I need to condition on X to find $P(Y>1)$ but I do not know to continue. Appreciate some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is
$$
f_{Y\mid X=x} (y\mid x) = \frac1x\cdot1_{(0,x)}(y).
$$
The joint density of $(X,Y)$ is then:
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) &= f_{Y\mid X=x} (y\mid x)f_X(x)\\
&= \frac1x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\cdot1_{(0,x)}(y)\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(x).
\end{align}
We compute the marginal density of $Y$ by integrating the joint density over the range of $X$:
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_y^\infty \frac1x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \lambda\cdot\Gamma(0,\lambda y),
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the upper incomplete gamma function, i.e.
$$
\Gamma(0,\lambda y) = \int_{\lambda y}^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}\ \mathsf dt.
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y>1) &= \int_{(1,\infty)} f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_1^\infty \lambda \int_{\lambda y}^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}\ \mathsf dt\ \mathsf dy\\
&= e^{-\lambda} - \lambda\cdot\Gamma[0,\lambda].
\end{align}
When $\lambda=1$, this is
$$
e^{-1} - \Gamma[0,1] \approx 0.148496.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y>1) = \int \mathbb{P}(Y>1 | X=x) \,dx = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{x} e^{-x} \,dx \approx 0.15
$$